# How insert from table A to Table B in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

i want insert from table A to table B
My code:

```
String sql = "Insert Into B (emsunitcode,gpsacquisition_datetime,insert_datetime) "
        + "Select emsunitcode,gpsacquisition_datetime,update_datetime From A";
  database.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

But it not work.
How insert from table A to Table B in sqlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()`.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but doesn't run it. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs.